# CSS:hover:after overlay breaks jquery on click for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jQuery lightbox setup with a number of 300x300px images that on click open the lightbox. I would like to be able to overlay an semi-opaque background and text information with the video titles on the CSS `:hover:after`.  The overlay works correctly and the lightbox works without the overlay code in place. But as soon as I combine the two the hover works but blocks the on click. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="screenShot" id="video1">
    <a href="#"data-videoid="21183190" videosite="vimeo">
        <img src="http://www.gorillacreativemedia.com/wp-content/themes/gorillashifter/img.php?mw=300&mh=300&src=library/images/noimage.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.screenShot{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin:20px;
}
.ScreenShot img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#video1:hover:after {
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding:100px auto;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I don't know if I should be trying to trigger this off of a Javascript function instead or if I'm missing something simple with the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The  tag has to wrap around the element that you're putting the hover event on. I changed the HTML to this:

```
<div class="screenShot">
    <a href="#" data-videoid="21183190" data-videosite="vimeo">
        <div id="video1">
        <img src="http://www.gorillacreativemedia.com/wp-content/themes/gorillashifter/img.php?mw=300&mh=300&src=library/images/noimage.png" />
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Kept the CSS the same and it appears to work as intended now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `z-index`:

CSS:

```
#video1:hover:after {
    content:'\A';
    position: absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding:100px auto;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    z-index:-1 //Generally lower than the element's z-index
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/843/

Comment: That hides the overlay behind the image. It looks like it works on your demo because like an idiot I forgot to change the image to a public url. When the image is actually there it hides the overlay and kind of defeats the purpose.